# Новомодное словечко "по ходу" (или "походу")

Tags: жаргон

Сейчас частенько можно слышать или читать в речи это слово паразит — "по ходу". Откуда оно вообще взялось и что означает? От слова "походить" или "по ходу пьесы"? Например, "Я, по ходу (или "походу"?) уже давно опоздала".

Comment: "По ходу" - усеченное "по ходу дела". Сколько себя помню, так всегда говорили на Урале, никакое это не новое

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во-первых, в письменных источниках "походу" обычно слитно. 
Во-вторых, я бы не сужал его значение до "похоже". Чаще всего используется вместо "кстати", "между делом". "Вероятно", "похоже" - это уже вторая составляющая.

При этом происхождение от "похоже" я не исключаю.
Хотя если искать на пути фонетической близости, то есть такое слово "походя". В одном из значений оно в чем-то близко "кстати". Или, как тоже уже сказали (Марк Из), - "по ходу дела". Так что тут - фифти-фифти.

Comment: А разве кстати и похоже не синонимы?

Comment: >А разве кстати и похоже не синонимы?  
 
Еще нет. )))
А они где-нибудь даются как синонимы? В каком значении?

Comment: Оба в значении кстати

Comment: По-моему, выражения, например, "Кстати, я опоздал" и "Похоже, я опоздал" имеют отчётливо разные значения

Comment: Допустим. И что?

Comment: Анализ этого оставим историкам науки в следующих десятилетиях. По ходу Ливанову приходилось расставаться с важными хорошими сотрудниками. В первую очередь – с Игорем Федюкиным. Его отставка была плохим знаком».========== На «похоже» здесь «по ходу» непохоже никак.

Answer (score 16):

Здесь по смыслу просится вводное "похоже". Возможно, от него и пошло... Созвучие явное.

Comment: Да. Но дело-то в том, что употребляется не только в этом смысле.

Comment: Да? В моем окружении это слово употребляют очень немногие.

Comment: В моем тоже. Хотя я не брезгую сайтами, где оно вполне в ходу. 
Но вся штука в том, что оно уже вовсю несется с экрана.

Comment: Возможно... Не замечала. Но не в этом дело. В вопросе был конкретный пример.

Comment: С экрана не слышала (потому, что не смотрю телевизор), а в сленговой речи встречаю часто. Впрочем, меня оно не очень раздражает - сейчас много куда худших слов)))

Comment: Приехала на праздники к дочке - и услышала обсуждаемое "по ходу". Попыталась заменить на "кстати" и на "похоже" - ничего не подходит. Просто выражение, привлекающее внимание к тому, что будет сказано дальше.

Comment: Викисловарь тоже утверждает, что походу = похоже (https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83)

Answer (score 15):

По всей видимости усечение от **по ходу дела**. Так как после усечения выражение стало напоминать слово "похоже", то стали использовать и в этом значении.

Answer (score 2):

"Походу"   - это дословный перевод с английского by the way, что означает "кстати".

Comment: Дословный? Где тут перевод слова way? И почему слитно?

Answer (score 1):

Согласна с Марком.
Это усеченная фраза "по ходу дела". Потому и раздельно.

Answer (score 1):

> Здесь по смыслу просится вводное "похоже".

Скорее всего, это и имеют в виду. Правда, некоторые используют это слово совершенно бездумно. Так, для связки слов...

> По всей видимости усечение от **по ходу дела**.

Только, к сожалению, не многие это понимают.

Answer (score 1):

Выражение было и есть популярно в криминальных кругах. Произошло от "по ходу дела/процесса".  Употребляется заключёнными ждущими  приговора в тюрьме.  Ну и очень популярное словечко там, а теперь вот и повседневную жизнь вышло...

Answer (score 1):

Походу - то же самое, как и слово похоже. Смысл слов одинаков, образование слова тоже одинаково. Причем тут слово паразит, это новое слово, так же как заимствования гайд, гид, лайк, аркада, пролонгация - почему эти не паразиты???

Answer (score 1):

В контексте молодежного дискурса = "судя по всему".

Comment: N3ver_Again, старайтесь давать более развернутые и обоснованные ответы

Comment: Единственный аргумент - личное наблюдение в ряде случаев и разных контекстах.

Comment: Хорошо. Просто подобные ответы автоматически попадают в список "некачественных".

Answer (score 1):

Слово "походу" чаще всего в подобных контекстах употребляется в значении слова **"выходит"** *(2. вводное слово. Стало быть, следовательно. Мысль эта, выходит, не так нова.)*. По крайней мере, не приходилось встречать ни одного случая, когда "походу" нельзя было бы заменить на "выходит". Исходя из этого, пишется "походу" слитно.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, кривая калька с англ. by the way (кстати, между прочим). Полагаю так потому, что впервые встретил это словосочетание в поганом переводе какого-то англоязычного фильма, за пару лет до распространения сабжа.

Comment: Вряд ли. Калька да еще кривая никогда не станет народным разговорным выражением, не пройдя стадию "официального" признания.

Answer (score 0):

Что касается смысла, то в качестве синонимов можно привести уже озвученные слова *«похоже»*, *«судя по всему»*, *«кажется»*, *«видимо»*.

А по поводу написания и пунктуационного оформления, Грамота.ру [говорит](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83) о *[раздельном написании](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=291742)* — «**по ходу**» — и о возможности *обособления запятыми как [вводных слов](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=235946)*.

Answer (score 0):

Учитывая тот факт, что слово "походу" употребляют в разных, совершенно не похожих ситуациях, оно не имеет определённого смысла. Обычное слово-паразит. Мне кажется здесь не нужно умничать и искать смысл или научно обосновывать его происхождение

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это видоизмененное молодежным сленгом "..в течении...".Типа как,в среде юнцов,  в 70х гг., взялись употреблять "старики" вместо "родители"?